# Action_Send_Multiple intent, but not sure how to build the array

Tags: android

So in my current form of my app, I am able to send an email with a single image using the following:

```
private void dispatchSubmitBonusIntent() {
        Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendEmailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendEmailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{submissionEmailAddress});
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "2019_" + riderNumToH + "_" + bonusCategory.getText() +"_" + bonusState.getText() + "_" + bonusCity.getText() + "_" + bonusCode.getText());
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent from aTOH App");
        if (mainPhotoPath != null) {
            sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(captureBonus.this, "net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor", mainPhotoUri));
            Log.v("MainImageFound", mainPhotoPath + "|" + mainPhotoUri);
            if (secondaryPhotoPath != null) {
                sendEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(captureBonus.this, "net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor", secondaryPhotoUri));
                Log.v("SecondaryImageFound", secondaryPhotoPath + "|" + secondaryPhotoUri);
            } else {
                Log.e("NoImageFound", "Image Not Found");
            }
        }
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Sending email..."));
    }
```

I am needing it to send up to two attachments, so I'm converting it over to an ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE. I have the following code, but I'm not sure what to put inside the for loop for it to work.

```
public void sendEmail(Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC,
                             String subject, String emailText, List<String> filePaths)
    {
        //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{submissionEmailAddress});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "2019_" + riderNumToH + "_" + bonusCategory.getText() +"_" + bonusState.getText() + "_" + bonusCity.getText() + "_" + bonusCode.getText());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent from aTOH App");
        //has to be an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (String file : filePaths)
        {
            File fileIn = new File(file);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email ..."));
    }
```

What do I put in the `for` section so the it will grab the one or two images that need to be attached?

EDIT 1: I made some changes based on the answer I was given, but it still isn't working. I get an error that says `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Tour%20of%20Honor/2019_541_AK6_1.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()` (That file path is correct though).

```
public void dispatchSubmitBonusIntent() {
    Log.e(TAG, "entering dispatchSubmitBonusIntent");

    //need to "send multiple" to use more than one attachment
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

    // Set up the email parameters
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[]{submissionEmailAddress});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "2019_" + riderNumToH + "_" + bonusCategory.getText() +"_" + bonusState.getText() + "_" + bonusCity.getText() + "_" + bonusCode.getText());
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent via TOH App for Android");

    // Get the attachments
    Uri mainPhotoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(captureBonus.this, "net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor", mainPhotoUri);
    Uri optPhotoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(captureBonus.this, "net.tommyc.android.tourofhonor", secondaryPhotoUri);

    //has to be an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    String[] filePaths = new String[] {mainPhotoURI.toString(), optPhotoURI.toString()};
    for (String file : filePaths)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }

    // Add the attachments to the email and trigger the email intent
    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email ..."));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one method for sending multiple attachments using an array

```
      public boolean sendEmailIntentWithMultipleAttachments(Context context,
                                                                String[] emailTo, String[] emailCC, String[] emailBCC,
                                                                String subject, String emailBody, List filePaths) throws ActivityNotFoundException {

                    final Intent emailIntent =
                            new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailTo);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, emailCC);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, emailBCC);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                    ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                    extra_text.add("Hello This is multiple Email Text"); 
                    ei.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);

                    if (filePaths != null) {
                        // has to be an ArrayList
                        ArrayList uris = new ArrayList();
                        // convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
                        for (String file : filePaths) {
                            File fileIn = new File(file);
                            if (fileIn.exists()) {
                                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                                uris.add(u);
                            }
                        }
                        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra
                                (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                    }
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sent mail"));
                    return true;

}
```

Create an imageArray like this and set to intent putParcelableArrayListExtra

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
String[] filePaths = new String[] {"sdcard/sample.png", "sdcard/sample.png"};
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Its working fine in my app

Comment: It isn't working for me. It looks like it isn't happy with my `FileProvider`. I'm trying to always reference the file on disk as my capture method has already saved it to disk. I want this method to just get the existing files and attach it to the email. I have edited my question to show the new code I'm using based on your suggestion.

Comment: I was able to fix it using the provided answer, so I marked it as correct.